# Parse data based of number of digits in quotes

Tags: text-processing

I have a large amount of data currently in the current format:

```
a:7:{i:0;s:4:"9999";i:1;s:4:"10000";i:2;s:4:"10001";i:3;s:4:"10002";i:4;s:4:"10003";i:5;s:4:"10004";i:6;s:4:"989";}
```

The numbers inside `""` before them have `s:4`. For numbers that are 3 digits  long this should be changed to `s:3` and digits that are 5 long should be `s:5` and so on.

The converted data should look like this:

```
a:7:{i:0;s:4:"9999";i:1;s:5:"10000";i:2;s:5:"10001";i:3;s:5:"10002";i:4;s:5:"10003";i:5;s:5:"10004";i:6;s:3:"989";}
```

Each data string `{}` is on it's own line in `data.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=';'

while read LINE
do

        set -- $LINE

        while [ "$1" ]
        do
                if [[ $1 =~ ^s:[0-9]+:\".*\"$ ]]; then
                        s=${1##*:}
                        printf 's:%d:%s%s' $((${#s}-2)) "$s" "$IFS"
                else
                        printf '%s%s' "$1" "$IFS"
                fi
                shift

        done
        printf '\n'

done < data.txt
```

This script sets the field separator to the semicolon character, and then iterates through the lines of `data.txt`, splitting each line into separate fields on the semicolon delimiter.  For fields that begin with `s:###:"..."` (for arbitrary values of `###` and `...`), the script calculates the length of the quoted string, and reformats the field using that length value and adding a trailing field separator.  Fields which do not match the form `s:###:"..."` are output verbatim, again adding back the trailing field separator.

```
a:7:{i:0;s:4:"9999";i:1;s:5:"10000";i:2;s:5:"10001";i:3;s:5:"10002";i:4;s:5:"10003";i:5;s:5:"10004";i:6;s:3:"989";};
```

Comment: Using a process per line is expensive (calling grep), when bash has pattern matching built into it using either `[[` or `case`.

Comment: @icarus Thank you for that suggestion.  I've incorporated it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
perl -pe 's/s:\d+:"(.*?)"/sprintf("s:%d:\"%s\"",length($1),$1)/ge'
```

Ex.

```
$ echo 'a:7:{i:0;s:4:"9999";i:1;s:4:"10000";i:2;s:4:"10001";i:3;s:4:"10002";i:4;s:4:"10003";i:5;s:4:"10004";i:6;s:4:"989";}' | 
    perl -pe 's/s:\d+:"(.*?)"/sprintf("s:%d:\"%s\"",length($1),$1)/ge'
a:7:{i:0;s:4:"9999";i:1;s:5:"10000";i:2;s:5:"10001";i:3;s:5:"10002";i:4;s:5:"10003";i:5;s:5:"10004";i:6;s:3:"989";}
```

You can add `-i` to perform the substitution on the file in-place.